# "MiKTeX Configuration Utility did not succeed" when trying to extend compiler limits

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I'm trying to add several plots to a report using `pgfplots` and I got an error about "TeX capacity exceeded". I saw [this](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/wiki/TeX-capacity-exceeded,-sorry) solution, but when I tried to enact it, I got a different error related to missing MiKTeX updates. I'd opened up a question here earlier on the subject, but I screwed something up in the mean time and, long story short, ended up having to reinstall MiKTeX altogether.

When I try to update the LaTeX format files, as it says in the previous link, I get the error in my question and a message saying "The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again". The aforementioned log file contains the following:

```
2019-11-24 17:56:07,950Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7251 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
2019-11-24 17:56:07,951Z INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-11-24 17:56:07,951Z INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex
2019-11-24 17:56:07,991Z INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-11-24 17:56:28,937Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7251 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
2019-11-24 17:56:28,937Z INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-11-24 17:56:28,938Z INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --dump=pdflatex
2019-11-24 17:56:28,943Z INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-11-24 17:56:29,321Z ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\Users\XXXXX XXXXX\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2019-11-24-175629.out'
2019-11-24 17:56:29,321Z FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2019-11-24 17:56:29,321Z FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="D:\Programas\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1"
2019-11-24 17:56:29,321Z FATAL initexmf - Source: 
2019-11-24 17:56:29,321Z FATAL initexmf - Line: 0
```

I changed my name to "XXXXX XXXXX" for privacy and because it does contain a space. It also contains an accented character, in case that's relevant.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Comment: Have you checked the makefmt output file? See `C:\Users\XXXXX XXXXX\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2019-11-24-175629.out`

Comment: That file directs me to another log file that says ```miktex-pdftex.exe failed on pdflatex.ini```, which is the config file the github page I linked to before says to edit (via the command prompt).

Comment: I would recommend that you follow all log file links. If I edit `pdflatex.ini` as suggested by the "solution" on GiHub, I get a `bad parameter value` for `font_mem_size=5000000`. IIRC, `4000000` is the MiKTeX upper limit.

Comment: So maybe the issue is that the solution itself doesn't work. Thankfully, I was since able to find a workaround. ```pgfplots``` can create plots as separate files, which it then inserts in the main pdf. It's not perfect, since it increases file size considerably and doesn't actually solve the problem, but it's acceptable for now.

Comment: It would be possible to increase the limits. I have created a MiKTeX issue here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/422

Comment: I meant that the number suggested there can't be used because it exceeds what MiKTeX can actually handle. Still, thank you for opening up the issue on GitHub.